# how to prove homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

[image]
How to prove the 2 nd part tof the problem.Independent proof is possible but here it is given that we will have to prove it from the previous result.I was able to do 1 st part only.The things that I observed is i(pi) + i(sigma) and i(pi • sigma) is of same parity.But could not prove it .if anyway we can can prove that we r done.I am asking for an easy approach to 2nd part .Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any two sets $A,B$,
$$\left|A\Delta B\right|=\left|A\right|+\left|B\right|-2\left|A\cap B\right|.$$
This means that
$$\left(-1\right)^{\left|A\Delta B\right|}=\left(-1\right)^{\left|A\right|}\cdot \left(-1\right)^{\left|B\right|}.$$

Can you see how to continue?

Comment: Yes ,because sigma is a bijection implies its inverse is also a bijection so,cardinality of sigma inverse (I(pi)) is same as cardjnality of I(pi).hebce we are done.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply .it really helped.

Comment: Am I correct??@guy

Comment: Yes, you are correct :)